# Imperative with pronouns - negative

Tags: verbs, grammar, pronouns

I was solving an Italian exercise about the Imperative with pronouns.

The exercise was giving wrong sentences to correct. I had a problem with the following two:

- Non vi piace la birra? Allora *non la ordinate*, prendete l'acqua!
- *Non ti fai* la doccia, vestiti e usciamo, è tardissimo!

I initially translated like this:

- Non vi piace la birra? Allora **non la ordinare**, prendete l'acqua!
- **Non ti fare** la doccia, vestiti e usciamo, è tardissimo!

I did it like this because I learned that "In the negative form, the pronouns can either precede the verb or merge with it at the end."

However, the only accepted correction was:

- Non vi piace la birra? Allora **non ordinatela**, prendete l'acqua!
- **Non farti** la doccia, vestiti e usciamo, è tardissimo!

Would both options be correct or is there a problem with my first attempt?

Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of the pronoun question, "non ordinare" in your first sentence doesn't fit because it's singular.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite peculiar, but the negative imperative for the second person *singular* is made with the infinitive:

> Ordina una birra (Buy a beer)
>
> Non ordinare birra (Don't buy beer)

This doesn't happen for the second person *plural*

> Ordinate una birra
>
> Non ordinate birra

(In English it would be ambiguous, but that's a different problem.)

So you cannot use the infinitive, because the subject is plural.

However, I see nothing wrong in “non la ordinate” instead of “non ordinatela”: the enclitic positioning of the pronoun is optional. Perhaps the second form is more common, that's all.

Similarly for the shower, but probably in this case “non farti” would be far more common than “non ti fare”; regional differences due to local languages may influence the choice.

Comment: I agree on almost everything, and add that _non ti fare_ sounds to me perfectly normal.

Comment: I agree too and  add that  *non la ordinate* is perhaps more familiar to me than *non ordinatela*, that looks a little akward, too long to pronounce.  I think that considering wrong the positioning of the pronoun before the noun is an outdated grammar rule, they said me that when (many years ago) I was at school, but now it is allowed.

Comment: From the point of view of a learner, "always use clitic pronouns with the imperative" is an easier rule to remember than "clitic pronouns are mandatory with the positive imperative and optional with the negative imperative". So maybe that book teaches this simplified rule, and gives answers to the exercises based on it. without bothering to add alternative correct versions.